# Run a gulp watch simultaneously than gretty

Tags: gradle, gulp, build.gradle, gulp-watch, gretty

I'm trying to run a `gulp watch` when running my Java web-app with Gretty.
I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) to run gulp from Gradle.

For the moment, I'm just able to run a single gulp build before the app run by doing this: `appRun.dependsOn gulp_build`

What I would like is that when I run the app, there is also `gulp watch` starting (task `gulp_default` in Gradle on my case), so that SCSS files are automatically compiled when I save them without having to restart the app.

I can't just do `appRun.dependsOn gulp_build` because gulp_default doesn't return anything, so the gradle task doesn't execute appRun.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: I may try to help but need a SSCCE, can you provide one?

Comment: @Opal Sure, here's one really simple example: https://github.com/ThibaultVlacich/gradle-gulp-sscce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way, but by using npm to start the app and not gradle.

I used the [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package. I start the app by doing `npm start` instead of `gradle appRun`, and I added this in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently \"gradle appRun\" \"gulp watch\""
}
```